# Select from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I need to select several columns from 2 tables:

```
Tab1
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3

Tab2
| Col1 | Col4 | Col5
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT A.*,B.Col4 
FROM Tab1 A,Tab2 B 
WHERE A.Col1=B.Col1 
AND A.Col2=='XXX'
AND A.Col3>5;
```

However this query concatenates two tables in some manner and **duplicates some rows**. What is wrong with it?

The expected result is this one:

```
Tab3
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
```

Comment: Please give an example of actual vs desired results. Not sure what you mean by "concatenates two tables"

Comment: reasons might be for x of a.col1 there be more than one row in b.col1. it is also possible that x features more than once in table a & b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the query you posted, but if the problem is that there are

> duplicates some rows

As you described then use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*, B.Col4 
FROM Tab1 A, Tab2 B 
WHERE A.Col1 = B.Col1 
AND A.Col2 = 'XXX'
AND A.Col3 > 5;
```

Or the other `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*,B.Col4 
FROM Tab1 A 
INNER JOIN Tab2 B ON A.Col1 = B.Col1 
WHERE A.Col2 ='XXX'
  AND A.Col3 > 5;
```

Comment: The second one works fine. But it's the same as user1183004 has posted and his post was downvoted twice. Don't understand why.

Comment: @YouKuper user1183004 and other users that got their answers down voted because they asumes that you are not joining the two tables, however, you are already joining them but using a different syntax. they haven't pointed out to the main problem with you which is the duplicate rows

Comment: Ok,thanks. Indeed, your second query works fine without DISTINCT. The problem was that I did not use INNER JOIN.

Comment: @YouKuper - That wasn't the problem. Whilst explicit join syntax is preferred it makes no difference if you use that or stick the equi join syntax in a `WHERE` clause as for `A.Col1=B.Col1`.

Comment: @Martin Smith: The magic is that with A.Col1=B.Col1 and DISTINCT it provides different result than INNER JOIN.

Comment: @YouKuper - It doesn't. That would be quite a major bug in MySQL. Quite likely you have made some other change to the query. The issue with `==` makes me think that you are clearly not supplying the exact query that you are running.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `=` instead of `==`.
If col1 is primary key of Tab1 and col2 is primary key of Tab2 and relation betweeen Tab1 and Tab2 is one to one, there is no way to duplicate record.

```
SELECT A.*,B.Col4 
FROM Tab1 A,Tab2 B 
WHERE A.Col1=B.Col1 
AND A.Col2 ='XXX'
AND A.Col3>5;
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL INNER w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

use that web side to practice and to understand inner, left, right join. Multiple queries ....

Answer (score 0):

Use join

```
SELECT A.*,B.Col4 
FROM Tab1 A JOIN Tab2 B ON A.Col1=B.Col1 
WHERE A.Col2='XXX'
AND A.Col3>5;
```

beware that in sql there is no ==  (double equal sign) to check equality instead use single (=)

Comment: `WHERE A.Col1=B.Col1` is a join.

Comment: Why this one is downvoted? It does exactly what I asked and works fine.

Comment: @YouKuper - Because apart from the correction of `==` (which was edited in after @swemon's answer appeared) this has identical semantics to your original query.

Comment: Oook. I haven't noticed it. Sorry.